# What is number chart on sniper rifle?

Tags: analysis, american-sniper

I was watching the movie "American Sniper", In the first 30 minutes scene ,when Chris Kyle is observing the Afghan woman and child carrying Russian Grenade.

There is a number chart pasted on his rifle,
What is it for?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A pre-calculated sight adjustment chart for the rifle/scope reticule (and presumably ammunition). *Range and Windage* adjustments.

Comment: This is very common among long-distance shooters. Particularly for wind and range adjustments, since even a light breeze can put you inches off target at a few hundred yards.

Comment: @SteveButler Or short-distance shooters with weapons that fire relatively slow projectiles.  I tape one of these charts to my laser rangefinder when I go hunting with a pellet rifle. :)

Comment: They also have a computer that can do this for them.  The computers can even handle things like Coriolis effects (about 1in at 1 mile, or so I have been told).  However, given the extreme nature of their job, it is not unreasonable that they do not perfectly trust their computer, and make sure they have an old fashioned table on hand in case the computer malfunctions.

Comment: In the field a sniper wouldn't have a computer handy to calculate out all of that stuff. Since the military is great for only giving them one type of ammo to shoot, it's easy to just print out windage and elevation corrections for a single load.